# Allow only letters, numbers and some foreign letters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I only want to allow users to use letters, numbers and some foreign letters. This works but it removes foreign letters (like öçşğ).

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $nick)
```

So I have used below to allow some foreign letters, but it still removes the foreign letters.

```
preg_replace("@[^A-Za-z0-9\- şıüğçİŞĞÜÇ]+@i","",$nick);
```

What is the correct approach for allow them ?

Comment: Use the `u` flag for unicode.

Comment: Could you please show me how ?

Comment: `....+@iu` <-- this `u`

Comment: I am getting this error > preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 14 in

Comment: Try to use `\s` instead of the space

Comment: I am confused. could you please write the correct preg_replace ? Thanks

Comment: I am confused by the requirement: *some foreign letters*. Are those in your regex the only *some* additional letters that you want to allow? Could you please also add an example nick string? Here is a [demo code](http://ideone.com/38x5BJ) (a [shorter version](http://ideone.com/Xh7e9R)). Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. Just need the `u` (PCRE_UTF8) modifier and you missed the letter "ö" ;)

```
preg_replace("@[^A-Za-z0-9\-\sşıüöğçİŞĞÜÖÇ]+@iu", '', 'Öm$ür Y_ağız');
```

returns `Ömür Yağız`

Untested, but you may be able to simplify the regex to:

```
@[^a-z0-9şıüöğçİ -]@iu
```

Comment: Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 15 in ...

Comment: Ah, in that case you have to substitute the characters with unicode values, e.g. `@[^A-Za-z0-9\-\s\x{011F}\x{011E}]+@iu` (I've only added `ğ` as an example)

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head if it's an extension like `mbstring` or a locale setting to support UTF-8 characters in strings, but it can be done :)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use language specific characters, you can use following construction, which more understandable than write all specific characters of your language in regular expression:

```
preg_replace("/[^\w\p{Latin}]+/", '', 'Öm$ür Y_ağız');
```

And replace "**Latin**" to your own unicode character set from http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: So this will only allow lating chars, correct ? How to allow only letters, numbers and these latin chars ?

Comment: That's right, it allows latyn chars, numbers and "_". If you want to allow letters, numbers and these latin chars my regular expression it's for you

Comment: There are no specific scripts for most languages, so for Turkish, you would have to use the Latin script which allows Turkish characters but allows unwanted characters from Spanish, French, and several other languages. As the amount of letters outside the A-Z range is usually in single digits, it is best to just list them.